# Run a test until it fails

Tags: bazel

In Bazel, you can re-run a test multiple times with:

```
bazel test --runs_per_test=<n> <target>
```

This is useful to reproduce conditions that lead a flaky test to fail.

The shortcoming of this approach, though, is that the tests will be run `n` times regardless of the results.

For tests that are flaky in very rare conditions, this means that you have to set `n` high, but this means you may have to scroll through a lot of text before you find the failing test's output.

Is there a built-in way in Bazel to run a test until it fails? Right now I'm using a `while` loop in Bash, which is good enough for my use case but not portable:

```
while bazel test --test_output=errors -t- <target_name>; do :; done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing `--notest_keep_going` will cause Bazel to exit as soon as a test fails. So, you could use `--notest_keep_going` in combination with an absurdly high `--runs_per_test`.